# amazon aws alarm notification to central console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new for AWS technology and I am wondering how I can send Amazon cloudwatch alert to central console.( by default alert send as email) I am looking the message as trap or short  message show on NOC console. I know it can go as SMS to mobile device via sns. but I am hopping there is some method(scipt,apps) to send this alert to central console to be monitor by NOC Eng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your email client, you can filter the CloudWatch emails, and script an appropriate trigger. I have seen this done with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this via a REST call (https command) as part of a SNS topic instead of sending an email.  The only catch is that you have to have your REST API available externally, which can create some security issues if implemented incorrectly.